# mysql inventory transactions - get list of serials on locations

Tags: mysql, sql, inventory-management

I have inventory DB design with tables `stock_transactions` and `stock_transactions_serials`. Stock transaction table holds all IN and OUT transactions from warehouses. Each transaction can have list of serials that go with it, this is recorded in `stock_transactions_serials` where index is stock_transaction_id+serial_id.

I need to compose a query that lists the list of serials on all locations where qty > 0. I have build SQL fiddle here to have some data to work on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/520bfa/5.

Currently my SQL is like this:

```
SELECT
    ST.id, 
    ST.warehouse_location_id, 
    ST.product_id,
    SUM(ST.quantity) AS qty,
    STS.serials AS serials 
FROM stock_transactions ST
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT stock_transaction_id, GROUP_CONCAT(serial_id) AS serials
    FROM stock_transactions_serials
    GROUP by stock_transaction_id
) STS ON STS.stock_transaction_id = ST.id
WHERE 
    ST.document_id = 9 
GROUP BY ST.warehouse_location_id
HAVING qty > 0
```

The result from this SQL is not quite right. QTY's are right but the serials are wrong... It's not taking into account serials that left or came into location with other stock transactions for this document.

Result should be:

Location 51 serials: 22229

Location 52 serials: 22221, 22222, 22223, 22224, 22225

UPDATE: just to make my question more clear. You move 5 computers with serial numbers A, B, C, D, E from location X to Y. Now you have 5 laptops with serials on location Y. Next you move one laptop from location Y with serial number A back to location X. And then another laptop with serial F from location X to location Z... I want to know what is the quantity of laptops (and which serials) on every location after all the transactions....

UPDATE2: would like to have solution also for items that do not have serials. For example I move 5 USB sticks from location A to location B. Then 2 from B to C. And finally another 2 from A to C. What are the quantities at each location.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh Your comment does not help me much unfortunately

Comment: I do not understand the sentence starting with `It's not incalculating`. Pls clarify the question.

Comment: @Shadow I have changed my question. I meant to say that my query is not returning the right serials on the location. It's not taking away the serials that left from a location and new serials that came into location with another transaction(s)...

Comment: I still do not get what you mean.

Comment: @shadow ok let me try this. You move 5 computers with serial numbers A, B, C, D, E from location X to Y. Now you have 5 laptops with serials on location Y. Now you move one laptop from location Y with serial A back to location X. And another laptop with serial F from location X to location Z... I want to know whats the quantity of laptops and which serials on each location after all the transactions....

Comment: Okidoki, much clearer now. In this case I would get the last ¬in` transaction for each serial because that would give you the actual picture.

Answer (score 1):

The current location of each asset can be derived from the last `in` type of transaction affecting a serial. You can get these using the following query:

```
select sts.serial_id, max(st.id) as max_in_id
from stock_transactions st
inner join stock_transactions_serials sts on sts.stock_transaction_id = st.id
where st.type='In'
group by sts.serial_id
```

Using the above query as a subquery you can get which assets were moved to which warehouse, providing you with the counts as well (in the absence of an opening inventory).

```
select st.warehouse_location_id,
       st.product_id,
       count(sts.serial_id) as qty,
       group_concat(sts.serial_id) as serials
from stock_transactions st
inner join stock_transactions_serials sts on sts.stock_transaction_id = st.id
inner join (
    select sts2.serial_id, max(st2.id) as max_in_id
    from stock_transactions st2
    inner join stock_transactions_serials sts2 on sts2.stock_transaction_id = st2.id
    where st2.type='In'
    group by sts2.serial_id) as max_ins on st.id=max_ins.max_in_id and sts.serial_id=max_ins.serial_id
group by st.warehouse_location_id, st.product_id
```

The above query assumes that you cannot have the same serial id for different products, which is implied by the PK on `stock_transaction_id`,`serial_id` fields.

Comment: Haven't had time to test yet but would this query work also for material that has no serials? For example 5 peaces from location X to Y, 3 from Y to Z, etc...

Comment: No, it would not, since that was not the question.

Comment: Forgot to mention

Comment: I have updated my question if you can help me out. Your query works perfectly for items with serials. I have tested extensively. But I would like to have a solution that works for items without serials as well. Meaning I need to find out quantities of each product at each locaiton

Comment: I'm sorry, but this completely changes the question because you cannot apply the same logic to items with no serial number, therefore I do not think it is fair to include this in your current question. You have to do a running total (a.k.a cumulative sum), or even better, maintain the stock levels in a separate table. There are lots of questions and answers around this here on SO. Pls do your own research first and post another question if you still cannot figure it out.